# Python setting global variables in different ways in 2.7

Tags: python, scope

I was trying to practice a concept related to setting global variables using diff methods , but the following example is not working as per my understanding .

```
#Scope.py

    import os
    x = 'mod' 

    def f1() :
        global x
        x = 'in f1'

    def f2() :
        import scope
        scope.x = 'in f2'

    def print_x() :
        print x

    def f3() :
        import sys
        sc = sys.modules['scope']
        sc.x =  'in f3'




    if __name__  == "__main__" :
        f1()
        print_x()
        f2()
        print_x()
        f3()
        print_x()
```

It gives the following result

```
in f1
in f1
in f1
```

While as per my understanding it shd result in

```
in f1
in f2
in f3
```

Can someone help me in understanding what am i doing wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this modified piece of code.

```
x = 'mod'


def f1():
    global x
    x = 'in f1'


def f2():
    import scope
    scope.x = 'in f2'
    return scope


def print_x():
    print(x)


def f3():
    import sys
    sc = sys.modules['__main__']
    sc.x = 'in f3'
    return sc


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f1()
    print_x()
    sc = f2()
    print_x()
    print(sc.x)
    sc = f3()
    print_x()
    print(sc.x)
```

The thing is that in the original `f2()` you actually import your `scope` module under name `scope` and modify its variable. And in following `print_x()` you refer to an unchanged `x` in `__main__`. In `f3()`, you reference your module by wrong name: to modify it, you should use `__main__` here. With `scope`, you're actually referencing the module that was imported in `f2()` (Try removing `f2()` call)... Which is clearly not what you want.